# Update XML node using XQuery

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a XML type variable @XMLData.

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML 
DECLARE @tempXML XML 

SET @xmlData =N'<ArrayOfResult>
<Result>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Text>This text should be updated to new text</Text>
</Result>
<Result>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Text>This text is okay</Text>
</Result>
</ArrayOfResult>';
```

I want to update the **Text** of the nodes where **ID** is 1.

I have tried this way

```
SET @tempXML = @xmlData
SELECT @xmlData;

SET @tempXML.modify('replace value of (/ArrayOfResult/Result/Text/text())[1]     with ("This text is okay")');

SELECT @tempXML
```

But here, I have to mention the node index [1] to update first node. 
How can I update the **Text** element which have **ID** = 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML 
DECLARE @tempXML XML 

SET @xmlData =N'<ArrayOfResult>
<Result>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Text>This text should be updated to new text</Text>
</Result>
<Result>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Text>This text is okay</Text>
</Result>
</ArrayOfResult>';

SET @tempXML = @xmlData
SELECT @xmlData;
```

--you can use a variable to pass in the id

```
DECLARE @id INT=1;

SET @tempXML.modify('replace value of (/ArrayOfResult/Result[ID=sql:variable("@id")]/Text/text())[1]     with ("This text is okay")');

SELECT @tempXML
```

Comment: @NoorAShuvo, just one hint: You can introduce the text you want to replace through a variable as well. If the value is taken from a result set's column, use `sql:column("ColumnName")`